# How to copy files defined in a list of source paths to a list of output paths in cmd or powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

i have a list of source files and a list of destination files in two variables, all delimited with spaces:

```
$srcFiles = C:/srcpath1/srcfile1 C:/srcpath2/srcfile2 ...
$dstFiles = C:/dstpath1/srcfile1 C:dstpath2/srcfile2 ...
```

how can I copy all src files to all output locations using either cmd or powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two arrays that are ordered appropriately, you can do something like the below:

```bsh
param(
    $srcFiles = @("$PSScriptRoot\src\file1.txt", "$PSScriptRoot\src\file2.txt"),
    $destFiles = @("$PSScriptRoot\dest\file1.txt", "$PSScriptRoot\dest\file2.txt")
)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $srcFiles.Length; $i++) {
    Copy-Item -Path $srcFiles[$i] -Destination $destFiles[$i] 
}
```

Personally, I might use a hash table for this instead of the two arrays.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7